# User registration and login problem

Tags: users

When I visit the registration page, or the login page, it says that I do not have access to that page. Do you have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably logged in to the site.

The user login and registration pages are not available for authenticated users, as it doesn't really make sense for a logged in user to login again or register.

Answer (score 2):

Additional to the cause suggested by @Clive assuming that you are using the normal registration option provided by core:

1. What is the registration mode set in User Settings in **Administer >> User Management >> User Settings** (admin/user/settings). If Only site administrators can create new accounts then it's possible that I reckon you wouldn't be able to register (I'm not completeley sure about it as I haven't tried it out myself), but however you should still be able to login.
2. Is there any custom code that modifies the menu path for login (user/login) and registration (user/register) for which the `access callback` might return `FALSE` not letting anyone visit that URL giving the message that you are not authorized to view that page.

Also any new menu path with these previously registered menu path that might have recently been added unwillingly could sometimes case confusions such way. You could try clearing the cache or even `cache_menu` table specifically as a long shot. Also try disabling any suspicious modules that were recently enabled following which this issue might have been encountered.